# where's libmagickwand-dev (I installed them all) and how can I include it to a C program

Tags: c, imagemagick, magickwand

I installed all the libmagick-dev packages (magickwand, magick++, etc) in Ubuntu 16.04 but I don't know where is the library... So I haven't included it to my C program.
I need to use the pixel level functions for a project I'm developing
When typing 'locate libmagick', I just get the /usr/share/doc stuff.
It's the docs, not the libraries.
I need to include the .h files to my program so I can manipulate images.
At the moment, I'm making tests for the image manipulations (simple programs that are in the imagemagick.org site wich use the magickwand API)...
But that's a thing I don't know how to do...
Where's the library?
That's a first step :(

Installed -dev Packages:
libmagick++-6.q16-dev (imagemagick C++ developer API)
libmagickcore-6.q16-dev (magickcore low-access API for C)
libmagickcore-6-headers
libmagickwand-6.q16-dev (magickwand C developer API)
libmagickwand-6-headers
I also installed the libmagickwand-dev package, though apt says it's a transitional package that could be removed...
I've read that those packages would be enough, but it seems it's not...
Thanks for your replies ;-)

Comment: Did you run `./configure; make; sudo make install`?

Comment: EDIT: I installed Debian yesterday... Didn't like Ubuntu at all :-/ 
Then, installed it on Debian. As far as I know, Debian doesn't need to compile. It installs precompiled packages using dpkg, and those ones are in the repositories (the Debian's packages collection) :( 
Am I wrong? It needs another config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a Ubuntu/Debian system, the libraries are usually under `/usr/lib`, or a subdirectory managed by the package installer + system architecture.

You can find them with...

```
find /usr/lib -name 'libMagick*'
```

The actual location is not terribly important as you should be leveraging `pkg-config`, or `MagickWand-config` utility for the required CC + LD flags.

For example

```sh
pkg-config --cflags --libs MagickWand
#=> -fopenmp -I/usr/include/ImageMagick  -lMagickWand -lMagickCore
```

or

```sh
MagickWand-config --cflags --libs
#=> -fopenmp -I/usr/include/ImageMagick
#   -lMagickWand -lMagickCore
```

So a simple MagickWand test can be something like...

```c
// test.c (creates a single rose.bmp image for testing)
#include <wand/MagickWand.h>

int main()
{
    MagickWandGenesis();
    MagickWand *test = NewMagickWand();
    MagickReadImage(test, "rose:");
    MagickWriteImage(test, "rose.bmp");
    DestroyMagickWand(test);
    MagickWandTerminus();
    return 0;
}
```

And can be compiled with..

```
cc -o make_rose_image $(pkg-config --cflags --libs MagickWand) test.c
```

Comment: I answered a wrong thing ¬¬ I mean, thanks, but it still doesn't work.... :( <br/>
When typed `pkg-config --cflags --libs MagickWand`, got
`-fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu//ImageMagick-6 -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-6 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu//ImageMagick-6 -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-6 -lMagickWand-6.Q16 -lMagickCore-6.Q16`

Comment: Excuse me for that awful code. I do not see the "edit" button... <br>
When typed `cc -o rose $(pkg-config --cflags --libs MagickWand)$ pruebaimg.c`, got `unrecognized command line option [that thing]` :-/

Comment: My mother language is spanish... That "pruebaimg.c" is your "test.c"

Comment: You have an invalid command line option `$` after invoking pkg-config. But your on the right track. You've located the libraries, and have identified the correct flags to pass to your compiler. Try `gcc -fopenmp -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/ImageMagick-6 -I/usr/include/ImageMagick-6 -lMagickWand-6.Q16 -lMagickCore-6.Q16 -o rose pruebaimg.c`

Comment: IT WORKS!! Thank you!

Comment: Now I have to make my pixel image :)
Could I ask you to look at my code?
I'm trying to draw a fractal ;-)
Just the lib's call lines. :D

Comment: Happy to help. If you found my answer helpful, please +1 it. If your original questions was answered, please accept the answer so future readers will know.  If you have additional questions, please open a new question.

Comment: OK :) Thank you. I wrote something else to explain what you said to me :)

Answer (score 1):

What I had to do was installing the libmagick-dev libraries. They were at /usr/lib. 
When typing `find /usr/lib -name 'libMagick*'`, got

```
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagick++-6.Q16.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagick++-6.Q16.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickWand-6.Q16.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagick++-6.Q16.la
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagick++-6.Q16.so.5.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagick++-6.Q16.so.5
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickWand-6.Q16.so.2.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore-6.Q16.so.2
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore-6.Q16.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickCore-6.Q16.la
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libMagickWand-6.Q16.la
```

And there they are! 
The libraries are in /usr/lib 
And a program who uses MagickWand is called by 
`cc -o output $(pkg-config --cflags --libs MagickWand) source.c`

:)